# Find 2D skeleton based on Voronoi diagram (C++/opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

I got the Voronoi diagram based on [this method](https://www.learnopencv.com/delaunay-triangulation-and-voronoi-diagram-using-opencv-c-python/). THe result looks like the following.

[image]

My goal is to find the **skeleton** of the long shape, and we can already see it from the diagram( the long horizontal curve). But the function from opencv only returns lots of facets with the form of `vector<vector<Point2f>>`. I can filter all the vertices in my shape, howerver, there are many points very near to each other. And the points runs in a circle, but I only want a sequence of points in one direction.

[image]

Anyone knows if there're functions for only extracting the points belong to the skeleton, and in only one direction?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to make weighted graph and find minimal spanning tree, it will give you connected set of points. Then find longest path between nodes, and it will give you terminal points.